# Start generalized azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am working on an azure deployment.  I am using some templates from github that creates a certain number of VM's based on a 'master image', puts them behind a load balancer, and allows access to them through RDP and ports.

Now, all this is working great.  I build my image, then I run sysprep and generalize it, shut it down, and spin up 40 copies.

The issue I am running into is what do I do if I want to update the 'master image'?

It won't let me boot it up, because it says it is generalized.  And I am having a hard time setting up a new vm and attaching the OS disk "not sure if this is the right way"

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am coming from a VMware VDI environment, where I would just boot up the master, make changes, shut down, and snapshot and redeploy.

Also I am using the new Azure interface, which I believe is called AzureRM.

Error message: `Operation Start VM is not allowed on VM xxx since the VM is generalized.`

Comment: How are you configuring this? through the portal or Powershell? xplat?

Comment: I am using a combination of powershell and the portal.  I make the image generalized through a command in powershell

Comment: searching yields only results on how to make it generalized, not how to "ungeneralize"...

Answer (score 1):

Like versioning, you have to create a new VM from the image made before, and then repeat the process again after your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not pretty, but it should work:

Spin up a fresh copy.  make your changes, then preform the sysprep / oobe process again, finally, generalize & capture.